# Why the closest to the nucleus electron has lower energy (contrary to Heisenberg)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, orbitals

According to shell theory the lowest energy electrons are on the $s$ level and are closest to the nucleus. This means they are localized in a smaller volume then other outer shell electrons and according to Heisenberg uncertainty relation they may have higher momentum $p$ and energy $E$. But it is on the contrary? How is this to be explained from physical (as less math as possible) point of view? Why is at all Eo constant if HUP is in power?

Comment: Why does Venus have lower energy than Earth, despite Kepler demanding it move faster?

Comment: @JohnDoty What do you mean? Venus is 35 km/s and Earth is 30 km/s.

Comment: @Mercury That's kinetic energy.  When you add in the potential (which is -2 * KE), Venus has a lower total energy than Earth.  It works in a similar way for electrons.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the closest to the nucleus electron has lower energy (contrary to Heisenberg)?

The first has nothing at all to do with the second. The energy content of the electron is determined by the energy absorption at a photon absorption or the energy release at a photon emission. Empirically it was determined that the electron with increasing photon absorption is further and further away from the nucleus and vice versa. And that there is a limit for the proximity to the nucleus, at reaching which no further approach takes place (unless one includes neutron stars in the consideration).

Heisenberg expresses only that with a measurement with our much too coarse measuring means impulse and position are not measured at the same time arbitrarily exactly.